# This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

react-native after upgrading

```
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

this is the warning
this warning appears

```
This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties
```